# Make MD5 raw in JavaScript

Tags: php, node.js, md5

I am converting PHP code to Node JS. I am facing a issue with MD5 binary raw  that is `MD5('String',true)` and getting `ï¿½Sï¿½ï¿½ï¿½<]zVC..zvï¿½ï¿½` . I have tried in Node.js but I am not getting same string on Node js.

Here is my code:

```
var md5 = require('md5');
var requestArray = [{
    "fname": "mobilenumber",
    "fvalue": '1234568970'
}, {
    "fname": "phone",
    "fvalue": '000000000'
}];

var post_data  = JSON.stringify(requestArray);
var m = md5(post_data);
```

I have tried to pass true parameter but it's not working.

Comment: post_data is string?

Comment: @lcssanches Please check my question again. i was edited after your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you already have the hex, just use a [hex2bin function](https://github.com/kvz/locutus/blob/master/src/php/strings/hex2bin.js),

```
var m = hex2bin(md5(post_data));
```

/

```
function hex2bin (s) {
  //  discuss at: http://locutus.io/php/hex2bin/
  // original by: Dumitru Uzun (http://duzun.me)
  //   example 1: hex2bin('44696d61')
  //   returns 1: 'Dima'
  //   example 2: hex2bin('00')
  //   returns 2: '\x00'
  //   example 3: hex2bin('2f1q')
  //   returns 3: false

  var ret = []
  var i = 0
  var l

  s += ''

  for (l = s.length; i < l; i += 2) {
    var c = parseInt(s.substr(i, 1), 16)
    var k = parseInt(s.substr(i + 1, 1), 16)
    if (isNaN(c) || isNaN(k)) return false
    ret.push((c << 4) | k)
  }

  return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, ret)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I run your code in my computer and have result :

```
'17740198bc4bb91e277091d30774b2c2'
```

Are you sure you use this code ?
Check update your module.

If you want create md5 bin, try use [kiat-md5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kiat-md5)

```
var m = md5(post_data, 'binary');
// t¼K¹'pÓt²Â
```

Comment: `17740198bc4bb91e277091d30774b2c2` is a hex string, it is not a raw binary. the raw binary version of `17740198bc4bb91e277091d30774b2c2`  looks like `t¼K¹'pÓt²Â`   , aka what you get if you run  `"\x17\x74\x01\x98\xbc\x4b\xb9\x1e\x27\x70\x91\xd3\x07\x74\xb2\xc2"` in a javascript console