# How to use hash_hmac function in node js

Tags: php, node.js, md5, cryptojs

Recently I have used same code on PHP and it's working fine but when I tried Node Js, it's not working for me. Please check once:

PHP

```
$signature = $ACCID . "POST" . strtolower(urlencode($url)).$requestContentBase64String; 
$hmacsignature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $signature, base64_decode($APIKey), true));
```

NODE CODE :

```
var signature = ACCID+"POST"+encodeURI(url).toLowerCase()+requestContentBase64String; 
var hmacsignature = base64.encode(crypto.createHmac('sha256', APIKey).update(signature).digest('base64'))
```

Please check what's wrong in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Your second line has two mistakes:

1. PHP APIKey is `BASE64_DECODE(APIKey)` while in Node.js code it is just `APIKey`
2. PHP hmacsignature is `BASE64(HEX(HMAC))` while in Node.js code it is `BASE64(BASE64(HMAC))`

Try this:

```
var hmacsignature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', Buffer.from(APIKey, 'base64')).update(signature).digest('base64')
```

Comment: i have tried your code but its not given me same response as like PHP

Comment: @PriteshMahajan check the updated code, and do share what are the different values if they don't match.

Comment: Please check my above code : 
var md5 = require('md5');
var requestArray = [{
    "fname": "mobilenumber",
    "fvalue": '1234568970'
}, {
    "fname": "phone",
    "fvalue": '000000000'
}];

var post_data  = JSON.stringify(requestArray);
var m = md5(post_data);
var requestContentBase64String = base64.encode(m);

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52128825/make-md5-raw-in-javascript/52147426?noredirect=1#comment91245305_52147426

Comment: PHP's urlencode and Node.js's encodeURI's behaviours are different. Use something like http://locutus.io/php/url/urlencode/